# Can I block or skip add_executable from third party repos? CMake FetchContent_Declare

Tags: github, cmake

```
    enable_testing()
    include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(
            ut
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boost-ext/ut.git
            GIT_TAG        v1.1.8
    )
    #FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ut)
    FetchContent_GetProperties(ut)
    if(NOT ut_POPULATED)
        FetchContent_Populate(ut)
        add_subdirectory(${ut_SOURCE_DIR} ${ut_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
    endif()
```

When including 3rd party repos using cmake, the list in clion shows all the executables and tests. Though discord suggested using `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` which helps. As it prevents these extra things from building when I build all.

What I want is just the libraries. Skip over `add_executable` lines in the third party cmake files.

If I have an executable named the same as them it'll show an error, example:

> add_executable cannot create target "ut_1" because another target with
> the   same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable
> created in   source directory
>
> Blockquote

Comment: Since the executables are no longer being built due to `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, what exactly is the issue? Are you annoyed because it is harder to find your executables in CLion's target list due to all the external project's executables showing up there or is the problem that you can't reuse a name that was used in the external proejct? Because depending on how CLion implemented their list the first problem might be fixable.

Comment: I also just checked the `ut` project you used as an example here, it has options to disable adding the tests, examples and benchmark executables. Many projects have such options to disable parts of their project if they aren't always needed. Have you looked for such options?

Comment: I'll check that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sadly, this is a fundamental limitation with the FetchContent approach. CMake offers no ways to remove targets once they've been added, and FetchContent is ultimately a call to `add_subdirectory`, which has no way of distinguishing between first-party and third-party targets.

Your only recourse is to patch the third-party build. You can do this by forking the project, trying to use the glitchy [`PATCH_COMMAND`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) option, or by working with upstream to namespace their targets.

When designing libraries to be consumed by FetchContent, one should always use a `<ProjName>_` prefix (or just `<ProjName>`).

Comment: Okay thank you for the info. I'll be sure to do the prefix in my libraries and for now on.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16414 there is talk about letting you put anything in a add_subdirectory into a namespace. This should come in handy. Though it's been worked on for 4 years.