# How to fetch a CMake dependency without building the entire project from the CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, build, compilation

I have the following problem with my project. I have a project structured in different subdirectories, but the important thing to know is that the main `CMakeLists.txt` file contains these lines:

```
...
add_subdirectory( deps )
...
```

where `deps` is the name of the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` for dealing with dependencies. In it, the relevant lines of code are:

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
   arsenalgear
   GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/JustWhit3/arsenalgear-cpp"
   GIT_TAG main
)

message( STATUS "Fetching arsenalgear..." )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable( arsenalgear )
```

The problem is that `FetchContent_MakeAvailable( arsenalgear )` will build the entire `arsenalgear` repository. I want to be able to perform only the installation part, not the whole build of tests and examples.

Is there any way to do this inside the `deps/CMakeLists.txt`? Thanks.

Comment: I thought you could use `BUILD_COMMAND` to select only the targets you need, but that is expressly prohibited. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448309/can-i-block-or-skip-add-executable-from-third-party-repos-cmake-fetchcontent-de/66448398#66448398) seems to suggest what you want is not possible.

Comment: @Botje is there any other and similar way to fetch a repo and decide which part of it to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at this project we can see

```
option( ARSENALGEAR_TESTS "Enable / disable tests." ON )
```

src: https://github.com/JustWhit3/arsenalgear-cpp/blob/538a169d295d7ce8578419b0c96b1b0b4a845a11/CMakeLists.txt#L38

so if you have [CMP0077](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0077.html) set to `NEW`, then you could use:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
   arsenalgear
   GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/JustWhit3/arsenalgear-cpp"
   GIT_TAG main
)
set(ARSENALGEAR_TESTS OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable( arsenalgear )
```

note: you can also Fetch in a subdirectory (i.e. creating a sub scope) so you can use `set(BUILD_TESTING OFF)`... while still having `BUILD_TESTING` set to `ON` (or whatever) for your own project...

Comment: Yes, I am the author of arsenalgear and implemented this option yesterday :)